# Stop a form being submitted before x hours of current time (javascript/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, momentjs

I have a website that has a booking form for a restaurant and the owner cannot take bookings for 6 hours before the current time.

Does anyone know how i can prevent a form being submitted 6 hours before the current time?

I found this snipped below that gets the current time minus 6 hours

Any help appreciated - hopefully can be useful to someone else also.

Thanks
Malcolm

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="moment.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        // manipulate
        /* 
          `add(key, value)` will add specified value to the key, key includes `years`, `months`, `weeks`, `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds` and `milliseconds`
          `subtract(key, value)` is the same as `add(key, -value)`

          `startOf(key)` will change current moment to the start of key, key includes `year`, `month`, `week`, `day`, `hour`, `minute`, `second`
          `endOf(key)` will change current moment to the end of key.
        */ 
        var time = moment().endOf('minute').subtract('hours', 6);
        $('body').append(time.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: implementing this logic in just javascript on the front end will probably not be sufficient as it is easy to bypass this and make direct requests to your server

Comment: I would rather work on the server-side rather than on the client side, because a very very very basic manipulation can work around your solution.

Comment: You could do it in pure-javascript, but it wouldn't be hard for someone to bypass it. Rather, look into using a server-sided approach upon a condition. For example, have the server set the time and have it check if the time matches the time you need, if it does allow them to place the order, if not disable the text-area or whatever you're using.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the form from submitting you should add server-side validation, which takes care of this logic.

You can prevent users from submitting the form via javascript, but it's easy to bypass client side validation and it neither is reliable nor best practice.

Comment: I agree with Alex - Using javascript validation will allow automated submissions (i.e. crawlers and bots).

Another issue is that javascript uses the user's system time, which may differ and is easily changeable trough the clock..

Server-side validation is the most reliable and will use the server's time instead of the user's.